# getRoles() ignored in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, acl, fosuserbundle, roles

My security yml is as follow

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_MEMBER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$,     role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register,   role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting,  role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/profile,    role: ROLE_MEMBER }
        - { path: ^/admin,      role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/group,      role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I have simply added a new role called `ROLE_MEMBER` and allowed only it to access the profile route.

If profile is set to `ROLE_USER` then this works fine.

I am using the FOSUserBundle, I have a fos_group and fos_user_group table. The joining table as an example is below.

[image: fos_user_group]

I have successfully used this table to give a user the member group, the roles for that group are just `ROLE_MEMBER`.

Using the following code within a controller I can see that a user has the roles of `ROLE_MEMBER` and `ROLE_USER`.

```
$user  = $this->getUser();
$user->getRoles();
```

This returns;

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "ROLE_MEMBER" [1]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" }
```

This is correct, I think. Yet the profile is inaccessible. If I change the profile to require `ROLE_USER` then it works and it can be accessed. The interesting thing is that using the debug section of Symfony I can see that in fact my user does not have the member role.

[image: no member role]

Is there a step I have missed that tells Symfony of the roles I have assigned my user, it seems that ensuring `getRoles()` returns the correct array does not work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to re-authenticate the user once I have added their Roles.

```
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            null,
            'main',
            $user->getRoles()
        );

        $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, from your own answer, you must re-authenticate you user.
If you don't want to, you just need to tell symfony2 to check if the session variable is the same as what is in database.

To do that, you must implement the `EquatableInterface` for your `User` class.

Then, implement the following method :

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
    if ($user instanceof User) {
        // Check that the roles are the same, in any order
        $isEqual = count($this->getRoles()) == count($user->getRoles());
        if ($isEqual) {
            foreach($this->getRoles() as $role) {
                $isEqual = $isEqual && in_array($role, $user->getRoles());
            }
        }
        return $isEqual;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If this function returns `false`, it will refresh roles in the authentication context.

From documentation [How to Create a custom User Provider (The Symfony CookBook)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html):

> Symfony also uses the username, salt, and password to verify that the
>   User has not changed between requests. Failing to serialize these may
>   cause you to be logged out on each request. If your User implements
>   EquatableInterface, then instead of these properties being checked,
>   your isEqualTo method is simply called, and you can check whatever
>   properties you want. Unless you understand this, you probably won't
>   need to implement this interface or worry about it.

Comment: When does that get called?

Comment: It's called on each request. See edited answer for more details.

Comment: I do not think tis would work for me. As I am changing the Roles immediately after registration within the registration controller. So there is no new request between the end of the controller and where I expect the roles to have changed.

Comment: I think it would, since there should be a redirection after each form submit (including the registration form). The redirection is on client side, ending up with a second request.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_MEMBER
```

to

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MEMBER:      ROLE_USER
```